# Kinect to BVH data

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

Is there any software to get BVH data directly from kinect? I searched on net and found Kinect BVH MoCap(http://tech.integrate.biz/kinect_mocap.htm) , but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no built in mechanism to save Kinect data at all - no matter what format you want it in.  The Kinect Studio does save off stream data, but I've not looked at the files to see what they look like internally.

You could look into the [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/), which provides functions to save off any of the 3 streams to a file.  You can save the file and then manipulate it as necessary, perhaps write a parser to translate the data.  Alternatively, you could manipulate the data before you save it off.

You could also write your own parser.  The `Skeleton` objects are serializable, which means you could save them to a `List` (or some other array type object) along with a time stamp.  When you are ready to save to the file, serialize the `List` and you will get a standard XML dump of the `List` and the `Skeleton` objects inside.  Again, you could write a function that just translate it into the proper format before saving it as well.

Comment: yeah, I have saved the skeleton data to file. Now I am trying to create BVH file from this data, but BVH file stores the euler angle of each bone, rather than the position. I dont have any idea on how to calculate euler angles from the data given by kinect.